# Reverse grepping

Tags: command-line, sed, awk, grep, efficiency

Let's say, I have a really big text file (about 10.000.000 lines). I need to `grep` it from the end and save result to a file. What's the most efficient way to accomplish task?

Comment: In addition to the excellent solutions posted, GNU `grep` has a `--max-count (number)` switch that aborts after a certain number of matches, which might be interesting to you.

Comment: @val0x00ff could you take a look at [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146263/why-is-tac-file-grep-foo-piping-faster-than-grep-foo-tac-file-proc?noredirect=1#comment236426_146263) question

Comment: Do you know how much hits you will have? When you think your grep will find 3 lines, start grepping and reverse afterwards.

Answer (score 47):

**[tac](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tac-invocation.html)/grep** Solution

```
tac file | grep whatever
```

Or a bit more effective:

```
grep whatever < <(tac file)
```

Time with a 500MB file:

```
real    0m1.225s
user    0m1.164s
sys     0m0.516s
```

**sed/grep** Solution:

```
sed '1!G;h;$!d' | grep whatever
```

Time with a 500MB file: Aborted after 10+ minutes.

**awk/grep** Solution:

```
awk '{x[NR]=$0}END{while (NR) print x[NR--]}' file | grep whatever
```

Time with a 500MB file:

```
real    0m5.626s
user    0m4.964s
sys     0m1.420s
```

**perl/grep** Solution:

```
perl -e 'print reverse <>' file | grep whatever
```

Time with a 500MB file:

```
real    0m3.551s
user    0m3.104s
sys     0m1.036s
```

Comment: @chaos, I think  `grep "somepattern" < <(tac filename)` will be faster.

Comment: @val0x00ff The `< <(tac filename)` should be as fast as a pipe: in both cases, the commands run in parallel.

Comment: If you're going for efficiency, it would be better to put the `tac` after the grep. If you've got a 10,000,000 line file, with only 2 matches, `tac` will only have to reverse 2 lines, not 10m. `grep` is still going to have to go through the whole thing either way.

Comment: If you put `tac` after the `grep`, it will be reading from a pipe and so can't seek.  That will make it less efficient (or fail completely) if the number of found lines is large.

Comment: @jjanes Can you expand a bit on that? I don't get your point, what is `tac` trying to seek?

Comment: @Bernhard Please look at [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146263/why-is-tac-file-grep-foo-piping-faster-than-grep-foo-tac-file-proc?noredirect=1#comment236426_146263)

Comment: @Bernhard If you tac a real file, it `lseek`s backwards through the file to read it backwards in chunks, and then reverses the lines in each chunk, remembering the line broken across chunks to put them back together.  If reading from a pipe, it can't do that.  It either needs to read the whole thing into memory, or write it to a temp file, or fail.

Comment: But if you put `tac` after `grep`, it only has to reverse the matched lines, not the whole file. So unless you're matching lots of lines in the file, it should be reasonably efficient.

Comment: @Patrick, et. al. So the “obvious” compromise is to do `grep (pattern) (input_file) > (temp_file); tac (temp_file) > (output_file); rm (temp_file)`, right? Note that, if the user wants to know line numbers of matches (by specifying the `-n` option), this will report correct line numbers in the original input file, whereas `tac (input_file) | grep -n (pattern)` will report, for example, the third-to-last line in the file as line `3`. (Of course, that *might* be what the OP wants.)

Comment: @chaos Would be please decipher the sed/grep solution functionality is some more detail? Where is the file in that command?

Answer (score 17):

This solution might help:

```
tac file_name | grep -e expression
```

Comment: `tac` is the GNU command. On most other systems, the equivalent is `tail -r`.

Comment: @Stéphane: On at least some Unix systems, `tail -r` is limited to a small number of lines, this might be an issue.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick, do you have any reference for that, or could you please tell which systems have that limitation?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, `tail -r /etc/passwd` fails with `tail: invalid option -- 'r'`. I'm using coreutils-8.21-21.fc20.x86_64.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu, as I said, GNU has `tac` (and only GNU has tac) many other Unices have `tail -r`. GNU `tail` doesn't support `-r`

Comment: So a more portable solution would be `(if command -v tac >/dev/null 2>&1; then file_name; else tail -r file_name; fi) |grep expression` (this should be a fair assumption since GNU Coreutils supplies both `tac` and `tail`, so a system without `tac` should have non-GNU `tail` and therefore support for `tail -r`).

Answer (score 10):

This one exits as soon as it finds the first match:

```
 tac hugeproduction.log | grep -m1 WhatImLookingFor
```

The following gives the 5 lines before and after the first two matches:

```
 tac hugeproduction.log | grep -m2 -A 5 -B 5 WhatImLookingFor
```

Remember not to use `-i` (case insensitive) unless you have to as that will slow down the grep.

If you know the exact string you are looking for then consider `fgrep` (Fixed String)

```
 tac hugeproduction.log | grep -F -m2 -A 5 -B 5 'ABC1234XYZ'
```

Answer (score 9):

If the file is really big, can not fit in memory, I will use `Perl` with [File::ReadBackwards](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::ReadBackwards) module from `CPAN`:

```
$ cat reverse-grep.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::ReadBackwards;

my $pattern = shift;
my $rev = File::ReadBackwards->new(shift)
    or die "$!";

while (defined($_ = $rev->readline)) {
    print if /$pattern/;
}

$rev->close;
```

Then:

```
$ ./reverse-grep.pl pattern file
```

Comment: The advantage of this approach is that you can tweak the Perl to do anything you want.

Comment: @zzapper: It's memory efficient, too, since when it read file line by line instead of slurp file in memory like `tac`.

Comment: can anyone add a -m support for this ? I'd like to test in on real files. See : https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ychaouche/cdbacdc114e7c401b16ac1643071b83a/raw/a40dbb6bc696c7e96237a3350d86e7a7eb217e54/gistfile1.txt