# how to append line only if line not set after specific word

Tags: sed, perl

I build the following sed cli in order to add the following line

```
force_https_protocol=PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2
```

after the line:

```
[security]
```

the sed cli :

```
sed  -i '/\[security\]/a force_https_protocol=PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2'  /etc/ambari-agent/conf/ambari-agent.ini
```

but the problem is when the line - `force_https_protocol=PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2`  is already after `[security]`

how to change the sed syntax in order to ignore adding the line if line already exist?

expected output

```
[security]
force_https_protocol=PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2
keysdir=/var/lib/ambari-agent/keys
server_crt=ca.crt
passphrase_env_var_name=AMBARI_PASSPHRASE
```

wrong file:

```
[security]
force_https_protocol=PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2
force_https_protocol=PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2
keysdir=/var/lib/ambari-agent/keys
server_crt=ca.crt
passphrase_env_var_name=AMBARI_PASSPHRASE
```

Comment: Is it guaranteed that `force_https_protocol=PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2`, when already present, will only appear on the lines that immediately follow `[security]`? In other words, can we assume that instances of `force_https_protocol=PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2` that appear elsewhere after `[security]` (if any) are not a concern to you?

Comment: yes - we not need to append  if the line is after [security] , or if the line is somewhere not after  [security] , then we need to append

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that all "force_https_protocol=PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2" in file are within the [security] tag and do not appear elsewhere

```
sed -e '/^force_https_protocol=PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2$/d'\
    -e '/\[security\]/a force_https_protocol=PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2' file
```

The idea is to delete all lines in file containing (only) the "force_https_protocol=PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2" string.

Explanation

```
/^force_https_protocol=PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2$/d'
```

Delete all lines containing the "force_https_protocol=PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2" string.

Tests

```
$ cat file
[security]
force_https_protocol=PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2
keysdir=/var/lib/ambari-agent/keys
server_crt=ca.crt
passphrase_env_var_name=AMBARI_PASSPHRASE

[security]
keysdir=/var/lib/ambari-agent/keys
server_crt=ca.crt
passphrase_env_var_name=AMBARI_PASSPHRASE

$ sed -e '/^force_https_protocol=PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2$/d'\
      -e '/\[security\]/a force_https_protocol=PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2' file
[security]
force_https_protocol=PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2
keysdir=/var/lib/ambari-agent/keys
server_crt=ca.crt
passphrase_env_var_name=AMBARI_PASSPHRASE

[security]
force_https_protocol=PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2
keysdir=/var/lib/ambari-agent/keys
server_crt=ca.crt
passphrase_env_var_name=AMBARI_PASSPHRASE
```

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. Using AWK

Here is a possible solution to the more general problem of adding a *string* to a labeled block of text (i.e. the lines of text that follow a specific label in a file and precede the next label or the ond-of-file) only if *string* is not present yet.

A simple approach is to walk the file backwards, keep track of the last time we encountered *string*, print it every time we encounter a specific label (just before printing the label itself), but only if we haven't seen it (*string*) yet, and forget about having encountered it (*string*) any time we come across a label. And, of course, reverse the result as the last step.

```
tac file | awk '
    /^force_https_protocol=PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2$/ {
        seen = 1
    }
    /^\[security\]$/ {
        if ( ! seen ) {
            print "force_https_protocol=PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2"
        }
    }
    /^\[[^]]*\]$/ {
        seen = 0
    }
    1' | tac
```

`tac`, included in [GNU Coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tac-invocation.html#tac-invocation), concatenates and reverses files line by line. How to reverse a file with other/standard tools is covered in several Q/As on U&L (for instance, [How does the command sed '1!G;h;$!d' reverse the contents of a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/233014/315749) and [Reverse grepping](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/146100/315749)).

This will not insert `force_https_protocol=PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2` after the first `[security]` in the following text snippet:

```
[security]
keysdir=/var/lib/ambari-agent/keys
force_https_protocol=PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2
passphrase_env_var_name=AMBARI_PASSPHRASE

[security]
...
```

---

To simply insert *string* after every occurrence of a label unless *string* is already there, the same approach may lead to:

```
tac file | awk '
    /^force_https_protocol=PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2$/ {
        seen = NR
    }
    /^\[security\]$/ {
        if ( ( NR == 1 ) || ! ( NR == seen + 1 ) ) {
            print "force_https_protocol=PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2"
        }
    }
    1' | tac
```

(This *will* insert `force_https_protocol=PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2` after `[security]` in the above text sample).

#### 2. Using sed

With `sed` you can use a variation of the `N;P;D;` cycle (which is abundantly covered in other Q/As on U&L; for instance: [How can I use sed to replace a multi-line string?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26284/315749) or [How to edit next line after pattern using sed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/285160/315749)).

This will insert the line `force_https_protocol=PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2` after a line composed solely of `[security]` only if the former is not already there.

```
sed '
  $! {
    N
    P
    /^\[security\]\n/ {
      /\nforce_https_protocol=PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2$/ b b
      i\
force_https_protocol=PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2
    }
    :b
    D
  }
  s/^\[security\]$/&\
force_https_protocol=PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2/'
```

This script:

- for each line, except for the last one (`$!`), appends a newline followed by the next line to the pattern space (`N`) (which already contains the current line);
- prints the first line in the pattern space (`P`); if that line is `[security]`...

  - ...and the next line is `force_https_protocol=PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2`, just deletes the first line from the pattern space and starts a new cycle (`b b`, `:b D`);
  - otherwise, prints `force_https_protocol=PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2` to standard output (`i\`) before deleting the first line from the pattern space and starting a new cycle (`D`);
- if the last line is `[security]`, replaces it with itself followed by a newline and `force_https_protocol=PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2` and prints the result (by means of the implied `p`).